# How many users are registered with security SE?

Tags: discussion, data-dump, data-explorer

Is it possible (pubic knowledge) to get the number of users registered with security SE? Ideally, I'd like to know the rep. of each one of them.

Personally, I'd like access to more statistics on the sites but I'll start with user count and rep.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/security/queries

Comment: Wow, that tool is awesome! I wish there was a little more documentation on how to use it, but still incredible!

Answer (score 7):

62.464 users. Any other question ;)?

I'm kidding (mostly: the number should be right).

You will see that SE philosophy is to be quite incredibly open, so you can have access to a very wide range of stats:

- You have lots of pages and information disseminated a bit everywhere, for instance I got the total number of users from [this page](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/66/year/security/) (you can access it through your profile > "Activity" tab > click on the top percentage label appearing right below you reputation),
- You can also create and execute your [own SQL queries](http://data.stackexchange.com/security/queries),
- There is also [an API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) available but I did not tried it,
- You even have access [all the ad targeting tracking data](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data) collected on your navigation!

In case of doubts, do not hesitate to also search on the general [SE Meta website](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), you will often find real gems out there :) !

Comment: This is a very concise list of all the available ways to get metadata. Quite incredible. SE does it right!

Comment: @MatthewPeters: Talking about metada, SE recently added a new privilege for people with over 25k rep: [access to site Analytics](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics).

Comment: Well, I've a way to go before then...

Comment: @TildalWave: Strange, the page I mentions clearly shows to different tabs on the right, one dedicated to user whose reputation has changed ("Reputation Change") counting around 2400 users, and one I suppose to count the total number of users ("Total Reputation"). However, each page seem to provide different number, if you go on http://stackexchange.com/sites you will see that it clearly states there are 66.636 users here. In fact, I think these number differences comes from different users states (registered users, unregistered ones, inactive or merged accounts).

Comment: You can also multiply the number of pages on http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/users by 36 to get close, which I guess is... kinda dumb given that there are easier ways to get that number. But, you know.